# matching text with dataframe column in r

Tags: r

I have a vector of word in r.

```
words = c("Awesome","Loss","Good","Bad")
```

And,I have following dataframe in r

```
ID           Response
1            Today is an awesome day
2            Yesterday was a bad day,but today it is good
3            I have losses today
```

What I want to do is words that are matching in Response column should be extracted and inserted into new column in dataframe. Final output should look like this

```
ID           Response                        Match          Count 
1            Today is an awesome day        Awesome           1
2            Yesterday was a bad day        Bad,Good          2 
             ,but today it is good      
3            I have losses today             Loss             1
```

I did following in r

```
sapply(words,grepl,df$Response)
```

It matches the words,but how would I get my dataframe in desired format?
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using base R - (credits to PereG too for help in concised answer to df$Counts)

```
# extract the list of matching words
x <- sapply(words, function(x) grepl(tolower(x), tolower(df$Response)))

# paste the matching words together
df$Words <- apply(x, 1, function(i) paste0(names(i)[i], collapse = ","))

# count the number of matching words
df$Count <- apply(x, 1, function(i) sum(i))

# df
#  ID                                     Response    Words Count
#1  1                      Today is an awesome day  Awesome     1
#2  2 Yesterday was a bad day,but today it is good Good,Bad     2
#3  3                          I have losses today     Loss     1
```

Comment: The question seems that includes the partial matching (losses & loss),  df$Count <- apply(sapply(tolower(words),grepl,df$Response),1,sum) works

Comment: @PereG thank you for this point. I missed this point which was quite important. You should write it as an answer! you deserve it

Comment: Thanks, but I could not find the solution to df$Words, so I thought I'd comment on yours, which was more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, which stores the matches in `list`s:

```
vgrepl <- Vectorize(grepl, "pattern")
df$Match <- lapply(df$Response, function(x) 
  words[vgrepl(words, x, ignore.case=T)]
)
df$Count <- lengths(df$Match)
```

Answer (score 0):

With df as the dataframe and using stringr the following will also work:

```
matches <- sapply(1:length(words), function(i) str_extract_all(tolower(df$Response),
                                                     tolower(words[i]), simplify = TRUE))
df$Match <- gsub('[,][,]+|^,|,$', '', apply(matches, 1, paste, collapse=','))
df$Count <- apply(matches, 1, function(x) sum(x != ''))
head(df)

#  ID                                     Response    Match Count
#1  1                      Today is an awesome day  awesome     1
#2  2 Yesterday was a bad day,but today it is good good,bad     2
#3  3                          I have losses today     loss     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution/suggestion in `tidyverse`. It reports the actual matches, not the patterns which were matched case-insensitive, but it should be sufficient for illustration purposes.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

words <- c("Awesome", "Loss", "Good", "Bad")
"ID;Response
1;Today is an awesome day
2;Yesterday was a bad day,but today it is good
3;I have losses today" %>%
  textConnection %>%
  read.table(header = TRUE, 
             sep = ";",
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE) ->
  d

d %>%
  mutate(matches = str_extract_all(
                     Response,
                     str_c(words, collapse = "|") %>% regex(ignore_case = T)),
         Match = map_chr(matches, str_c, collapse = ","),
         Count = map_int(matches, length))
```